# Symfony pager - componets - query problem

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, pager

I use symfony 1.4.11 .I have next component class:

```
class companiesComponents extends sfComponents {

    public function executeCompanylist(sfWebRequest $request) {



        // And the URL
        if (!isset($this->url)) {
            throw new Exception('Please specify the URL');
        }

        // Save the page
        if ($request->getParameter('page')) {
            $this->setPage($request->getParameter('page'));
        }

        // Create pager
        $this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Companies', sfConfig::get('app_ads_per_page', 5));
        $this->pager->setQuery($this->query);
        $this->pager->setPage($this->getPage());
        $this->pager->init();
    }

    protected function getPager($query) {
        $pager = new Doctrine_Pager($query, $this->getPage(), 3);

        return $pager;
    }

    protected function setPage($page) {
        $this->getUser()->setAttribute('users.page', $page, 'admin_module');
    }

    protected function getPage() {
        return $this->getUser()->getAttribute('users.page', 1, 'admin_module');
    }
```

I have action:

```
public function executeAll(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Companies')->getAllCompany();
        $this->url = '@companylist';
  }
```

And I have allSucess.php

```
 <?php include_component('companies', 'companylist', array(
        'query' => $query,
        'url' => $url,
        'noneFound' => __('You haven\'t created any ads yet.')
        )) ?>
```

In my Companies Table class

```
   public function getAllCompany()
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery('a')
    ->andWhere('a.active = ?',1)
             ->leftJoin('a.Owner o')
           ->leftJoin('o.Profile p')
           ->andWhere('p.payed_until > NOW()')

     ->addORDERBY ('created_at DESC');
}
```

And it is do not work. I get all my record "companies" from database,but  they are not selected according to the my query...
When I make

```
  public function getAllCompany()
      {
        }
```

or when I comment

```
 // $this->pager->setQuery($this->query);
```

I still get all my records :(

In logs I see :

```
Template: companies … allSuccess.php 

Parameters:
$query (NULL)
$url (string)
```

When I make

```
 public function getAllCompany()
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery('a')
    ->andWhere('a.active = ?',1)
             ->leftJoin('a.Owner o')
           ->leftJoin('o.Profile p')
           ->andWhere('p.payed_until > NOW()')

     ->addORDERBY ('created_at DESC');
 return $q->execute();
}
```

I have error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine_Collection::offset()
```

I do not understand how it get all records, and where I made mistake :(

Thank you!

Comment: install XDebug, you'll have a full stack trace instead of only an error message. By the way, it should be `addOrderBy`, not `addORDERBY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `->execute();` text from the return statement in the getAllCompany() function ... the DoctrinePager executes the statement - you don't need to ...

```
public function getAllCompany()
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery('a')
    ->andWhere('a.active = ?',1)
             ->leftJoin('a.Owner o')
           ->leftJoin('o.Profile p')
           ->andWhere('p.payed_until > NOW()')

     ->addOrderBy('created_at DESC');
 return $q;
}
```